# Linear system of pde with non constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

I'm a physicist and during my research work, I found a system of linear pde with non constant coefficients that I have to study, since I have totally no experience about systems of pde and I have even problems to find some references. It would be really great to have some advice about how to face the problem. What I would like to do is of course find a solution of this system but even proving the existence of the solution can be a first great step. So thank you in advance for any possible help or some good references. Here is the link to the system:
[System of pde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmwLP.jpg)
[image]

Where we have three indipendent variables $(x,y,z)$ and three dependent functions $(N_1,N_2,N_3)$. The functions $\omega_i:R^3\rightarrow R$ $f_i: R^3\rightarrow R $, $N_i:R^3\rightarrow R $ are all smooth functions. Given that the matrix of coefficients are all singular I don't know how to proceed even about the classification of this system. Like I said I would be interested in a local solution or at least the proof of the existence of the solution. Any reference or help about this system will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to be able to solve the set of 3 equations for any specific $f_i$, or is it more complicated than this?

Comment: yes for any specific $f_i$, thanks for asking.

Comment: Ok, so the way I would try to solve it is by differentiating two equations against a given variable in order to find a common term. For instance, if you differentiate the first by $\partial_z$ and the second by $\partial_x$ you will find the same $\partial_x \partial_z N_2$ in both cases and be able to substitute. (It's the way we do in non-linear optics when we have similar coupled equations)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! i will try to do like you said.